# IE7 jquery .each on array

Tags: jquery

Having some problems with IE7 on jquery $.each, this gives me
an "Object does not support...."

```
arr = arr[1].split('::');
$.each(arr, function() {
   item = $(this).split("#_#");
});
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a `split` method. Also, what's `item`? You haven't declared it anywhere. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the jquery extended version. `split` is a native javascript method, not a jquery method.

```
$.each(arr, function() {
   item = this.split("#_#");
});
```

*Note: I'm assuming here that the `item = ...` line is just an excerpt from a longer method.*

UPDATE per @user1158040's comment: To get this to work with IE7, you may need to declare the array as an actual array object rather than an array literal. So instead of something like this:

```
var arr = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'];
```

You'd do this:

```
var arr = new Array('abc', 'def', 'ghi');
```

Comment: ok thank you, so I need to use a for loop here? Why do chrome, firefox and safari support this then?

Comment: You can use a for loop if you want to use plain javascript. You can also use the jquery `$.each` if you prefer. Either one will work.

Comment: Well, I found a solution. I had to declare a variable = new Array(); berfore the split within loop. IE7 bug.